# How to append a function call to a golang struct?

Tags: go, data-structures

I have the following go code which I was wanting get interfaces working:

https://play.golang.org/p/A29etweYN_

to provide the following output:

```
Gate: Evaluation ID U0 NOR true 0 0
Gate: Evaluation ID U1 NOR false 0 1
Gate: Evaluation ID U2 NOR false 1 0
Gate: Evaluation ID U3 NOR false 1 1
```

I am finding it difficult to understand why the commented out line

```
//OutputY: gateNor(InputA,InputB)
```

does not work - gateNor is a function which I want to call and append to the Gate struct

What would be a more elegant way to implement this?

```
type Gate struct {
   Id      string
   Funct   string
   InputA  string
   InputB  string
   OutputY string
}

func (g *Gate) Notify() error {
    fmt.Printf("Gate: Evaluation ID %s %s %s %s %s\n",
        g.Id,
        g.Funct,
        g.OutputY,
        g.InputA,
        g.InputB,
    )
    return nil
}

gate0 := &Gate{
    Id:      "U0",
    Funct:   "NOR",
    InputA:  "0",
    InputB:  "0",
    OutputY: gateNor("0", "0"),
    //OutputY: gateNor(InputA,InputB),
}
```

gateNor returns the string true for input A=0 and InputB = 0,
for the gate0 (ID U0) struct following output is working:

```
Gate: Evaluation ID U0 NOR true 0 0
```

Comment: gateNor is a function that is meant to evaluate the logical gate NOR function for the two inputs of A and B for a given gate struct. I have already created the a functioning gateNor function - full code available in the link to play.golang.org is working apart from my understanding/lack of knowledge in how to do this with structs and to create a better data structure to enable this to expand further.

Answer (score 3):

For example,

```
gate0 := &Gate{
    Id:     "U0",
    Funct:  "NOR",
    InputA: "0",
    InputB: "0",
}
gate0.OutputY = gateNor(gate0.InputA, gate0.InputB)
```

Or, more elegantly,

```
func NewNORGate(id, a, b string) *Gate {
    gate := &Gate{
        Id:     id,
        Funct:  "NOR",
        InputA: a,
        InputB: b,
    }
    gate.OutputY = gateNor(gate.InputA, gate.InputB)
    return gate
}

func main() {
    gate0 := NewNORGate("U0", "0", "0")
    gate1 := NewNORGate("U1", "0", "1")
    gate2 := NewNORGate("U2", "1", "0")
    gate3 := NewNORGate("U3", "1", "1")

    GetEvaluation(gate0)
    GetEvaluation(gate1)
    GetEvaluation(gate2)
    GetEvaluation(gate3)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/WC-jlV-jqd

Or, most elegantly,

```
func NewNORGate(id, a, b string) *Gate {
    gate := &Gate{
        Id:     id,
        Funct:  "NOR",
        InputA: a,
        InputB: b,
    }
    gate.OutputY = gateNor(gate.InputA, gate.InputB)
    return gate
}

func main() {
    GetEvaluation(NewNORGate("U0", "0", "0"))
    GetEvaluation(NewNORGate("U1", "0", "1"))
    GetEvaluation(NewNORGate("U2", "1", "0"))
    GetEvaluation(NewNORGate("U3", "1", "1"))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/TOPuwSJ-xe

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to the members of Gate within the object-initializer; you could do something like:

```
inputA, inputB := "1", "1"
gate3 := &Gate{
    Id:      "U3",
    Funct:   "NOR",
    InputA:  inputA,
    InputB:  inputB,
    OutputY: gateNor(inputA,inputB),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not too elegant, but I'd rather define a method

> to append a function call to a golang struct

```
type Gate struct {
   Id      string
   Funct   string
   InputA  string
   InputB  string
}
func (g Gate) OutputY()string{
   return gateNor(g.InputA, g.InputB)
}
```

and have

```
g.OutputY()
```

lazily on demand. `g.OutputY()` not much more verbose then `g.OutputY` and laziness can matter in case of hard computation. Also on demand you get consistent value of `g.OutputY()`. How another way you assume maintain `g.Output` after changing say `g.InputA="1"` ?